# Alternative ways to apply a user defined aggregate function in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I am trying to apply a user defined aggregate function to a spark dataframe, to apply additive smoothing, see the code below:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark as ps
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, col, collect_list, concat_ws, udf

try:
    sc
except NameError:
    sc = ps.SparkContext()
    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([['A', 1],
                            ['A',1],
                            ['A',0],
                            ['B',0],
                            ['B',0],
                            ['B',1]], schema=['name', 'val'])


def smooth_mean(x):
    return (sum(x)+5)/(len(x)+5)

smooth_mean_udf = udf(smooth_mean)

df.groupBy('name').agg(collect_list('val').alias('val'))\
.withColumn('val', smooth_mean_udf('val')).show()
```

Does it make sense to do it this way? To my understanding this does not scale well, since I am using a `udf`. I also fail to find the exact working of `collect_list`, the `collect` part in the name seems to indicate that data is 'collected' to the edge node, but I assume that data is 'collected' to various nodes?

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> To my understanding this does not scale

Your understanding is correct and the biggest problem here is `collect_list` which [is just good old `groupByKey`](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html). Python `udf` has much lesser impact, but it doesn't make sense to use it, for simple arithmetic operations.

Just use standard aggregations

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum as sum_, count

(df
    .groupBy("name")
    .agg(((sum_("val") + 5) / (count("val") + 5)).alias("val"))
    .show())

# +----+-----+
# |name|  val|
# +----+-----+
# |   B| 0.75|
# |   A|0.875|
# +----+-----+
```

Comment: One follow-up question; how do you know that collect_list uses `groupByKey`? If it is a long/complex answer, I can post this as a new question on SO.